# Can I get a ToolStripControlHost reference from the control it hosts?

Tags: c#, winforms

In the following code, a control class is created that derives from `ToolStrip`.  That control then creates an embedded (private) `ToolStripControlHost`, and sets its `Control` to a new `TextBox` control.  A single public member is provided, which returns a reference to the embedded `TextBox` control for external use.  As follows...

```
public class StatusToolStrip : ToolStrip
{
    private ToolStripControlHost _status = new ToolStripControlHost(new TextBox());

    public TextBox StatusTextControl { get { return (_status.Control is TextBox) ? (TextBox)_status.Control : null; } }
}
```

My problem is that I need to get access to the `ToolStripControlHost`.  I realize that I could simply add a public member and return it directly, but I'm curious as to why it seems to be impossible to walk backwards from hosted control to host.

So, my question is this:  can I get from the `TextBox` control what its host is?  Or, for that matter, even determine that it is hosted at all?

Thus far, I have found no way to determine, by looking at the `StatusTextControl` member (i.e. the hosted `TextBox` control), whether or not it's even in a control host, let alone what that host is.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Parent` of the control returns the `ToolStrip`. So then it's possible to search to `ToolStrip` for the control. Something like:

```
private static ToolStripControlHost Find(Control c) {
    var p = c.Parent;
    while (p != null) {
        if (p is ToolStrip)
            break;
        p = p.Parent;
    }
    if (p == null)
        return null;

    ToolStrip ts = (ToolStrip) p;
    foreach (ToolStripItem i in ts.Items) {
        var h = Find(i, c);
        if (h != null)
            return h;
    }
    return null;
}

private static ToolStripControlHost Find(ToolStripItem item, Control c) {
    ToolStripControlHost result = null;
    if (item is ToolStripControlHost) {
        var h = (ToolStripControlHost) item;
        if (h.Control == c) {
            result = h;
        }
    }
    else if (item is ToolStripDropDownItem) {
        var ddm = (ToolStripDropDownItem) item;
        foreach (ToolStripItem i in ddm.DropDown.Items) {
            result = Find(i, c);
            if (result != null)
                break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: This seems to work well.  Note however, that part of the problem I had in arriving at such a solution was that I was originally working in the ToolStrip's `LayoutCompleted` event, which appears to fire prior to the assignment of `Parent`.  Which is why I could never find a good starting point.  Once I relocated some code to the form's `Load` event, my luck improved.